# Unresolved external symbol in public struct

Tags: c++, typedef

[image]Ok first off I have a feeling that what ever I did is ridiculously stupid but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any way I am new to C++ so thanks for teaching me.

I declared a public `typedef struct` in a header file.

I use it in the header file but never use it in my main. For some reason the file with my main is throwing a error that some aspects of it are never defined but I don't define them because I don't use the,

there's a good bit more but its irrelevant

Main.cpp just has sfml code that opens a window and runs a few voids bassed on user input. Those voids do use the structure but never Main.cpp. Can someone help me fix the error.

Thanks sorry if the answer is easy and this is a waste of time.

My Simplified SFML Code

```
    typedef struct KeyStruct {
        static sf::Image Img;
        static sf::Texture Tex;
        static sf::Sprite Sprite;
    }Key;

static void DrawKey(string key)
    {
        sf::Clock clock;
        //Declair Key
        Key Key;
        Key.Img.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/A.png");
        if (key == "A")
            Key.Img.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/A.png");
        else if (key == "D")//ect
        Key.Tex.loadFromImage(Key.Img);
        Key.Sprite.setTexture(Key.Tex);

        //Open Window
        sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(Key.Img.getSize().x, Key.Img.getSize().y, 32), "Key", sf::Style::None);

        //Handle Events
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        //While Open Loop
        while (window.isOpen())
        {
            window.clear(sf::Color::Transparent);
            window.draw(Key.Sprite);
            window.display();

        }
    }
```

Main

```
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(100, 100, 32), "Main Window", sf::Style::None);
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        //Handle Events
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            //Key Presses
            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) {
                if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::A)
                    MakeKey::DrawKey("A");
                else if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::D)
                    MakeKey::DrawKey("D");//ect
            }
            //Close
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        window.clear(sf::Color::Transparent);
        window.display();
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Can you try to reduce your code to create an example we could throw straight into a compiler and get the arrors you suggest?

Comment: Honestly I feel like doing that would be hard but i can easily just plug in my sfml code if u want

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily suggest doing that. Rather try to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you can.

Comment: sorry I said that then proceeded to do it lmao

Comment: What does the actual error message say?

Comment: You're using `typedef struct` (where the typedef is redundant anyway in C++) to reinvent namespaces... badly.  C++ supports namespaces directly.

Comment: I added a screenshot. Thanks for your effort in helping me.

Comment: If i'm doing it badly how should I go about doing it good? I can easily make it a new namespace idk y that didn't occur to me.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly you are using them, otherwise the linker would not be complaining about missing definitions.

In your Main.cpp file add the following lines.

```
sf::Image KeyStruct::Img;
sf::Texture KeyStruct::Tex;
sf::Sprite KeyStruct::Sprite;
```

But if you are absolutely sure you are not using them, then why not delete them from the struct and see what happens.

Comment: I am using them just not in the file that throws the error

Comment: Unresolved references are a linking error. They apply to the program as a whole not to any individual file. Have you tried my suggestion? It should solve your problem (despite the down vote).

Comment: Ya i did the issue was I was declaring them as static. They shouldn't have been static. Thanks for responding.

Comment: @JacobKrumholz That makes sense. Static class members are quite an advanced feature of C++, but I assumed you wanted them for some reason.